# search in a web using python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

I want to make some code that can input text in a web; i.e. in the web page http://www.dictionary.com/ look up a word. The code I found was the following (I'm using Python 3.5):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

value= {'q', 'something'}
value= urllib.parse.urlencode(value)
value= value.encode('utf-8')
f= urllib.request.Request('http://www.dictionary.com/', value)
g= urllib.request.urlopen(f)
print(g.geturl())
```

However, `print(g.geturl())` prints http://www.dictionary.com/, the same link I had at the beginning. I want it to search 'something' in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

`geturl()` simply returns the URL of the page, you need to use `read()` function.

```
print(g.read())
```

Comment: I still get the same web page. I want the object g to point to the following page: "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/something?s=t", which is the equivalent of searching 'something' in the dictionary.

Comment: in the link you posted here, there is __/browse/__ which doesn't exist in the original code you posted. maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: I don't think I expressed myself correctly. Using python, I want to search 'something' in the dictionary. So I would start in the link http://www.dictionary.com/  and get to http://www.dictionary.com/browse/something?s=t%22

Answer (score 0):

The URL structure is something like this for example

```
           baseUrl                 + searchTerm
"http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ + "something"
```

The following code can help you do that

```
import requests
value = "something"
res = requests.request(method="GET",url="http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + value)
print res.content
```

Comment: Is there any way to actually input the word in the browser?

Comment: If u wanna input the word..using headless browser is the way to go ...check out python selenium library to do that

Comment: What would you like to do after giving input and sending request ??

Comment: I want an object so that object.geturl() = dictionary.com/browse/something?s=t.

Comment: Cant get you ..are you trying to construct url to give request

Comment: imagine going to dictionary.com and searching 'something'. I want python to input 'something' in the search bar and take me to the web page 'dictionary.com' redirects you to after searching 'something'